# How to SelectLayerByAttribute Xcoordinate and Ycoordinate

Tags: arcpy

I am having trouble selecting by attribute when I am trying to select by the Xcoordinate and Ycoordinate. For example

```
 arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Manhole_ly","NEW_SELECTION",'"Xcoordinate" = 2817018.499512')
```

This will not select but I have no trouble selecting when using the following.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Manhole_ly","NEW_SELECTION",'"OBJECTID" = 447')
```

Is there something special that has to be done on the X and Y coordinate fields?

Comment: Equivalence testing of real values is [fraught with danger](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm).  Always use a range test.

Comment: Are you sure that Xcoordinate value exists exactly as written in your submitted code?

Comment: @Vince, how would I do that? Thank you.

Comment: @KJDavidson, I copied it form the Xcoord field.

Comment: I can get it to select if I use less than and greater than but even when I use between etc I cannot get it to give me the feature I want that is based off the x coord

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/77193)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the basic laws of binary computers is to never trust the conversion of any floating-point value except zero.  This is because computers don't store "2817018.499512", but break it into sign, exponent, and mantissa, then [encode those values in a bytestream](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) (float = `0x4a2befea`).  If the value you want is other than that bit pattern, the test will fail.  Worse yet, there are text values that cannot be represented exactly in IEEE float or double, which means any value they match won't be the value you requested. It's also quite likely that the text value you're searching with was rounded for display in the first place (especially if it has less than 15 significant digits), so you can't be sure of the value in dataset anyway.

What you really want is to "range test" the query value, by testing greater than or equal to the value minus a tolerance AND less than the value plus a tolerance:

```
SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Manhole_ly","NEW_SELECTION",
        '"Xcoordinate" >= 2817018.4995115 and "Xcoordinate" < 2817018.4995125' )
```

If 0.0000005 is too small an *epsilon*, increase the value until the test succeeds.

Comment: I just got that. I went to your link and read the article and came to the same  conclusion as you showed. You beat me to the punch. Thank you for your help and the link.